# Trying to get a PC to boot off a bootable SD card that is inside an USB attached Android device

Tags: usb, external-sd, linux, htc-desire-hd, disk-drive

First, I'd like to make myself look less a madman than I may have appeared to be.
I wanted to have a bootable USB stick with me at all times, but it's less convenient because it's an extra object and it's easier to lose, forget etc. Then I thought, I have an Android phone, and it has a micro SD in it; perfect.
Not all PC's can boot off a card reader, but the phone itself **is** a card reader when attached as a disk drive.

Or at least so I thought. Turns out that my netbook BIOS (tested on Asus eeePC) refuses to see it as an external harddrive; it only recognizes it as a generic USB device and doesn't offer an option to boot from it.
The device has a name "Android phone" or smth, so it seems to me that it doesn't work as a "pure" card reader, and instead still manifests itself as a phone.

Can it be somehow overridden?

Comment: I don't know, if it is possible. Maybe you should ask this question to the manufacturer of your phone. I guess, if you write them an e-mail they might tell you the answer. I could imagine, that the phone itself will have to make itself known to the pc and that this might be coded in a way, that it needs a running operating system. But I'm really just guessing. In anyway let us know, if it they answer and it is possible.

Comment: This looks like it might be a duplicate of this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/optimal-linux-distro-to-install-to-sd-card-to-use-as-usb-bootloader-for-pc

Comment: Al Everett, yes, in essence they are the same; I wasn't aware of its existence because I originally posted mine on SuperUser. But the question you are referring to doesn't ask outright how to overcome the issue; the issue was found out only during the discussion. Mine sort of does ask.  I'm a complete novice at SE, so I don't know if it's mauvais ton to edit the title of my question to make it even more prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See my answer to this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/optimal-linux-distro-to-install-to-sd-card-to-use-as-usb-bootloader-for-pc/12027#12027).

Short answer: Yes, it's possible, with a custom recovery, but I'm not sure I'd recommend it due to my experience with my phones not charging in recovery.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done with an Android phone due to the driver installation requirements that Android has before it will connect the SD card to the PC as removable storage. The Android OS requires basic (charging/connection) drivers to be installed before it will act as removable storage.

Because these drivers can't be installed in POST, the phone will not offer the SD card as a storage medium.

There might be a way to do it in Android, but I suggest you flag your question for moderator attention and request migration to [Android SE](http://android.stackexchange.com) if you want a possible Android solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux distros, it can be done with an Android app called [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=en).

Comment: Holy mother of... THANK YOU. I don't think this app was around when I first asked the question, and frankly, I abandoned the idea soon after. Two and a half years later, now that you've shown me the way, the game is on again! I will check this and approve your answer if it works.